# Working with XML and DataSets

Tags: c#, xml, dataset

In C# and .Net 4.5.2, I am able to create a DataSet that populates when it runs the ReadXml function. Then, I have a DataGridView, which gets columns and data from the DataSet based on what it reads from the XML file.

My question is this, how would I go about doing the reverse?

Basically, I'm being told to make a database without using a database, which leads me to xml files. I'm also tasked with making the program detect if the XML file is there or not (which I know how to do), and if it's not there, create it. I also cannot use a datagrid view, instead a series of bound controls, like textboxes and checkboxes.

My trouble is connecting those controls dynamically to a DataSet that has all the columns I need (based on an array or something similar), so that I can create a new XML file when I happen to need to.

I apologize if this is confusing, because it's confusing the heck out of me.

Edit: Re-wording mostly: How do I create a DataSet and cycle through/save it's information without a connection to an actual database?

Comment: How about using data models and xml serialization?

Comment: The problem is is he's giving this task to an amateur. This is my first real world experience, so there's quite a bit that I don't know, such as what you just described. I'll have to look into both of those things.

Comment: In this case you can write dataset as xml. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zx8h06sz(v=vs.110).aspx) is an article.

Comment: Thank you. That works towards writing to the XML. I guess my next issue is working a DataSet to bound controls.

Comment: There we go. Just figured out what I needed to know. If you could, want to place an answer and I'll upvote you? :)

Comment: Glad that it helped for you. Added as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You populating data to your DataSet from xml file by using [ReadXml()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Data.DataSet.ReadXml(v=vs.110).aspx) function.  And for storing your data from DataSet to xml file you can simli use [WriteXml()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Data.DataSet.WriteXml(v=vs.110).aspx) function.

Also here is an article how to work with DataSet and Xml: [Using XML in a DataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/84sxtbxh(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

To create a data-bound UI you use the Data Sources panel in Visual Studio. Change the data source's UI type from DataGridView to Details and drag it to the design surface. See this page for details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ckyxa83.aspx